# Restringir rotas vue router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Eu estou trabalhando em uma aplicação de postagem de artigos e gostaria que o usuário tivesse acesso para editar apenas o seus projetos.

Atualmente, caso eu mude o id do artigo manualmente, eu tenho acesso para editar conteúdo de outro usuário.

Então eu gostaria de restringir o acesso a rota e o redirecionar a uma página de status 403.

Essa é uma parte do meu código.

```html
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'



import Perfil from '../components/perfil/Perfil'
import EditarObra from '../components/mesa/EditarObra'
import Auth from '@/components/auth/Auth'
import CadastroDados from '../components/baseDados/CadastroDados'
import NotFound from '@/components/template/NotFound'
import { userKey } from '@/global'


Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '*',
    component: NotFound,
  },

  {
    name: 'login',
    path: '/login',
    component: Auth,
    meta: {
      requireLogin: true,
    },
  },

  {
    name: 'cadastroDados',
    path: '/basededados',
    component: CadastroDados,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },

    {
    name: 'perfil',
    path: '/perfil/:user',
    component: Perfil,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },
  
  {
    name: 'EditarObra',
    path: '/mesa/:id/editarobra',
    component: EditarObra,
    meta: { requiresAuth: true },
  },

  
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  },
  routes,
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const json = localStorage.getItem(userKey)

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    const user = JSON.parse(json)
    user ? next() : next({ path: '/login' })
  } else {
    next()
  }

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireLogin)) {
    const user = JSON.parse(json)
    user ? next({ path: `/perfil/${user.user}` }) : next()
  } else {
    next()
  }


})

export default router
```

Answer (score -2):

Certo, essa sua lógica da rota serve para verificar se o usuário esta logado.

Para verificar se ele pode ou não editar, a validação tem de ser feita ao entrar na rota e tentar carregar o conteúdo da postagem.

Ai o ideal é a validação ser feita no back-end, pois se for feita apenas no front-end, alguém pode simplesmente abrir o console, ver qual a URL e mandar um PUT para editar e conseguiria editar mesmo sem usar sua aplicação.

Comment: Eu pensei exatamente isso, então antes de tudo fiz a validação no meu backend. Gostaria também de fazer esse redirecionamento no forntend pra não precisar tratar na página.

Comment: Na minha opinião, há 2 opções e ambas a serem feitas "na página".
1 - Escrevendo na própria página, num lifecycle do Vue(`beforeCreate`, `created`, `beforeMount` ou `mounted`)
2 - no `beforeEnter` especifico da rota e não no geral, conforme a doc do [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#routes), você pode especificar um `beforeEnter` por rota.

Para a segunda opção eu só não sei se é possível passar dados do `beforeEnter` para o componente, talvez adicionando no `to`... se não quando o usuário puder, fará 2 chamadas iguais...

Comment: Nesse caso seria interessante usar Nuxt com SSR, assim você colocaria a validação na página dentro do `asyncData`, assim faria a validação direto no server e se o usuário não tivesse acesso, va devolvia pro usuário a página redirecionada direto do server.